# Why is the result of the code -5, not -4?

Tags: python

I thought the result was -4. But the result is -5. Could you explain the reason to me?

```py
result = 0
for i in range(5, -5, -2):
    if i < -3:
        result += 1
    else:
        result -= 1

print(result)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please copy and paste your code here instead of storing it in an image.

Comment: Why would you expect the result to be `-4`?

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation
range(start_value, end_value, step)

so in your code

```
result = 0
for i in range(5, -5, -2):
    if i < -3:
        result += 1
    else:
        result -= 1
    print(i,result)
print(result)
```

could you add the print( i , result) after the else for check the behavior of your variable.